# How to change the name of element in MarkLogic

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I want to do this change

From:

〈aaa〉
    bbbbbb
〈/aaa〉

To:

〈bbb〉
    bbbbbb
〈/bbb〉

by using MarkLogic, XQuery.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `xdmp:node-replace()`
Refer - [xdmp:node-replace](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace)

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is often to use [xdmp:node-replace](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace). However, this assumes both that the data you wish to modify is already inside a document in the database and that you are not performing any conflicting updates to that document.

When it's not possible to use xdmp:node-replace, your next best option is to modify the document in-memory and then insert the entire document into the database.

The easiest way to modify the document in-memory is to use mem:replace from the [XQuery Memory Operations library](https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations).

The most performant way to modify a document in memory is to write a [recursive descent tree](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/xquery-recursive-descent/) optimized to the structure of that document.

Answer (score 0):

If the node is not in a document, there is always the naive approach:

```
〈aaa〉 bbbbbb 〈/aaa〉 ! <bbb>{.}</bbb>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is also built in to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:document-insert("/test1.xml",
<root>
<child1>
<aaa>bbbbbb</aaa>
</child1>
</root>
);
doc("/test1.xml");
xdmp:node-replace(doc("/test1.xml")/root/child1/aaa,<bbb>bbbbbb</bbb>);
doc("/test1.xml");
```

Comment: If you want to copy everything from aaa node into bbb node, then the node-replace should be
`xdmp:node-replace(doc("/test1.xml")/root/child1/aaa,<bbb>{doc("/test1.xml")/root/child1/aaa/node()}</bbb>);`